# Syncfusion Asp.Net Datagrid: How to return error from CRUD class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I have an Syncfusion Asp.net grid performing CRUD operations.

```
public ActionResult Insert(CRUDModel<Source> newItem)
{
    using (var context = new ImageStormEntities())
    {
        context.Sources.Add(newItem.Value);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json(newItem.Value);
}
```

cshtml:

```
@Html.EJS().Grid("DataGrid").DataSource(ds => ds.Json(ViewBag.datasource).UpdateUrl("/Management/Update").InsertUrl("/Management/Insert").RemoveUrl("/Management/Remove").Adaptor("RemoteSaveAdaptor")).Columns(col =>
{

    col.Field("id").IsPrimaryKey(true).Visible(false).Add();
    col.Field("ResourceGroup").HeaderText("Source VM Resource Group").Add();
    col.Field("VMName").HeaderText("Source VM Name").Add();
    col.Field("imageVersion").HeaderText("Image Version").Add();

}).ActionFailure("OnActionFailure").AllowTextWrap(true).TextWrapSettings(text => { text.WrapMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.WrapMode.Header); }).AllowPaging().FilterSettings(filter => { filter.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.FilterType.Menu); }).EditSettings(edit => { edit.AllowAdding(true).AllowEditing(true).AllowDeleting(true).ShowDeleteConfirmDialog(true).Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.EditMode.Dialog); }).Toolbar(new List<string>
    () { "Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel" }).Render()
```

On the page, I have:

```
<script>
    function OnActionFailure(args) {
        alert(args.error.status + " : " + args.error.statusText);
    }
</script>
```

That returns a simple toast message when values break the db constraints, but values are empty.
I want to send usefull info to user.

I can catch the error,  what do I return to make this work.
Also, I would rather the use got a Messagebox to discharge rather that a toast.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your controllers code this will fix your issue

To

```
public ActionResult Insert(CRUDModel<Source> newItem)
{
  using (var context = new ImageStormEntities())
    {
     if(newItem.Value! = null)
     {
        context.Sources.Add(newItem.Value);
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
     else
     {
        throw new Exception("Empty values cannot be inserted");//Add custom 
        exception message 
     } 
    }

 return Json(newItem.Value);
}
```

and in your js add lime this

```
<script> 
   function OnActionFailure(args) { 
     var errorMessage = args[0].error.responseText.split("Exception:")[1].split('<br>')[0];  //extract the message from args 
    alert(errorMessage); 
    //you will get exact error that you have returned from serverside in errorMessage
 } 
</script>
```

Comment: @jlo-gmail..is this helpful for you

Comment: It only works when: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to"Development" ! It is not nice to deploy an application with this settings.